# Tratar evento ao fechar navegador

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com problemas em relação a esse tratamento de evento ao fechar o navegador utilizando javascript.

Pesquisei um pouco e achei uma ideia através do **onbeforeunload**:

```
<script> 

    window.onbeforeunload = fecharJanela  

    function fecharJanela(){  
        return "Você realmente deseja fechar a janela?"  
    }  

</script>
```

Mas com esse script ao atualizar a página ou até mesmo quando clico para direcionar a outro link do mesmo domínio ele pergunta se desejo realmente fechar a página, o que no meu caso não é interessante.

Alguém tem uma ideia de como consigo capturar o evento somente no momento em que o navegador ou a aba for fechada?

Se consigo um retorno booleano no momento que houver esse evento para tratar isso no meu javascript, visto que terei que mostrar um modal personalizado antes que o navegador seja fechado.

Valeu!

Comment: Olá Samuel, infelizmente é impossivel capturar o evento de fechamento, os unicos eventos disparados são beforeunload e unload, que na verdade são disparado até mesmo quando ocorre uma paginação (muda de página ou site) na mesma aba. Não existe evento especifico para isso, todas tentativas de tratar isso são gambiarras usando o evento `mouseout` no `window`

Answer (score 5):

**Pra abrir um prompt perguntando se voce deseja sair:**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Você tem certeza que deseja sair?';
};
```

Se você tiver usando Jquery:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  return 'Você tem certeza que deseja sair?';
});
```

**Caso você queria executar algo antes de sair da página**

*Lembrando que você não poderá redirecionar a pessoa para outro link por questões de segurança*

```
window.onunload = function() {
    alert('Valeu, falow.');
    //Seu código aqui
}
```

Se você tiver usando Jquery:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
  alert('Valeu, falow.');
  //Seu código aqui
});
```

Espero ter ajudado! Abs!